# How to display HTML texts in string-array of ListView

Tags: android, html

I created a ListView program such that when a list item is clicked, it will open into a NewActivity. Now, i have made a string array to populate the ListView. The texts i want to display in the NewActivity has both italics and bold characters well formatted. I have converted the texts into HTML
My question is; How can display this HTML texts in item array form. 
For Instance: HTML-Text-Here I have tried CDATA but there's no way i can fix it inside the  code in the string.

**This is what i tried that didn't work:**

```html
<item>"<![CDATA[ <p><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>The Love Pillar</strong></span></p>
<p>I Believe in love, the love of pure heart, sent..</p> ]]>"</item>
```

**Here is my String.xml**

```html
<resources>

<string-array name="DescriptionLyrics">
        <item>
</item>
        <item>No.1 LyricsHere</item>
        <item>No.2 LyricsHere</item>
        <item>No.3 LyricsHere</item>
        <item>No.4 LyricsHere</item>
    </string-array>
    
    
    
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will categorize this solution in two stages.

**Stage 1**

Instantiate your TextView
e.g
TextView newTextView;

In your **Activity.java**, in the onCreate
set

```js
newTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.htmlFormattedText1aa)));
```

In Your **String.xml** set

```html
<string name="htmlFormattedText1aa">"<![CDATA[ <p><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>The Love Pillar</strong></span></p>
<p>I Believe in love, the love of pure heart, sent..</p> ]]>"</string>
```

If you have TextView defined in your String;
newTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.htmlFormattedText1aa)));

=====**Stage 2**=====

If you want to pass the array string items through Adapter

Instantiate your TextView
e.g
TextView newTextView;

*Now, get data from previous activity when item of activity is clicked using intent*

```js
String newDescription = intent.getStringExtra("brandNewDesc");
```

*I have already defined "brandNewDesc" in my ListViewAdapter and sent it to Activity.java using intent.putExtra*("brandNewDesc", models.get(i).getBrandNewDesc());

Now in your Activity.java set mBrandNewDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(newDescription));

Finally in the **String.xml** set thus;

```html
 <item>"<![CDATA[ <p><font color="#ff0000"><b>The Love Pillar</b></font></p>
<p>I Believe in love, the love of pure heart, sent..</p> ]]>"</item>
```

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the code as

```
<item><p><font color="#ff0000"><b>The Love Pillar</b></font></p>
<p>I Believe in love, the love of pure heart, sent..</p></item>
```

Because! I already used this type of lists and paragraphs in my own project.

Comment: the texts appear as plain text. The color, bold character formats embedded didn't show. What do i do???

Comment: If i copy & paste the texts directly, the texts appear to be combined together without spaces and margin. Is there another way i can maintain the text markup style???

Comment: @Joseph You can use the static method in java class which returns Html.fromHtml("your html code"); and you can easily collect the required HTML content to use in TextView and other Views. Maybe, It helps - Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<item>"<![CDATA[ <p><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>The Love Pillar</strong></span></p>
<p>I Believe in love, the love of pure heart, sent..</p> ]]>"</item>
```